# Numpy module not found despite being in path

Tags: osx, python, path

I am having trouble with the module on python. Here is my path variable,

```
/opt/local/bin /opt/local/sbin /Developer/usr/bin /usr/local/git/bin /usr/X11/bin /Users/oskarniburski/.rvm/bin /usr/X11R6/bin /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/local/git/bin /usr/X11/bin /Users/oskarniburski/.rvm/bin
```

and as seen, it goes through 3.3 and 2.7 therefore should it not find the numpy module in python? I cannot do the euler intergration without the numpy module, so I am curious as to what is the solution. I tried reinstall numpy with pip install numpy
, but it did not solve my problem (as numpy module is already in python2.7 framework.) Therefore I am not sure why it is unable to locate numpy module. Any help?

The error I get originally was

```
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Now, after some changes, I get the error:

```
$ python eulerintegration.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eulerintegration.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from type_check import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import multiarray
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Answer (score 3):

You need path to `numpy` in `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, not in `PATH`. Also, look at [site module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) to find out, where python normally searches for its modules and at [distutils page](http://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#install-index) to find out about normal installation of extension modules and their location.

Location of numpy depends on your Linux distributive: for instance, in Debian 7 I have numpy installed in `/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.6/numpy/...`, but you might have it installed e.g. in either `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` or `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. As for the difference between `site-packages` and `dist-packages` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387928/whats-the-difference-between-dist-packages-and-site-packages). `/usr/local/..` is used for programs, manually installed by system administrator, including those installed with `pip`, while `/usr/..` is used for programs installed via your distribution's package manager, e.g. `apt` for Debian or `yum` for Red Hat.

Comment: Hey @Bob, how can I access my python path environment variable?. ie: in what file (like bash_profile) can I find it to change it.

Comment: @RaksoZrobin You can set it in `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` like `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, but read `man bash` to note the difference between interactive and non-interactive and login and non-login shells and their config files.

Comment: Tried changing the .bashrc file, but still not luck. this is my bash right now. I am clearly confused. Thanks for the help so far though.: [[ $- != *i* ]] && return # return if not interactive

fish


PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: @RaksoZrobin ok, could you type `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` in your terminal and then check, whether it helps python to `import numpy` just for now? I'm still not sure, that your `numpy` is there, it might be in other locations I suggested. And once again, you don't need `$PATH`, you need `$PYTHONPATH`. :) Also, I didn't understand the meaning of "[[ $- != i ]] && return # return if not interactive fish PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages". Is it excerpt from your config file?

Comment: Yeah it is from the bashrc source file. I can import the numpy module when using python, activating the python environment and then working from there. But I cannot when I am trying to just use python programs in the terminal. I am sorry for the trouble!

Comment: @RaksoZrobin No worries. Didn't you forget to restart terminal after editing your configuration files? You've got to do that for bash to see changes in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10837/discussion-between-bob-and-rakso-zrobin)

Comment: @RaksoZrobin you need to add the `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to your or `_/.profile` files. Basically, whenever anyone suggests doing something to `~/.bashrc` you should do it to `~/.bash_profile`. That's because OSX's terminal starts login shells by default. Linux (at least all the ones I've seen) start interactive, non-login shells by default. Login shell's don't read `.bashrc`, see my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/570323/151431) for a brief explanation of the differences.